# Exchanging Costa Rican Colones in Nicaragua

Tags: money, exchange, costa-rica, nicaragua

We arrived on the bus to Nicaragua recently and read that the best way to exchange Costa Rican Colones to Nicaraguan Cordobas was at the border.

We have about 89,000 Colones (approx. $154) in cash that we want to change. A guy at the border was offering us a maximum of 4000 Cordobas (approx $132). We thought this was extremely low so we decided against it.

The problem is, we didn't realise how difficult it is to change colones inside Nicaragua.

We're stuck with it now and really don't want to get a bus back to the border.

Does anybody know where we can change colones inside Nicaragua?

Answer (score 4):

In Nicaragua, currency exchange is a open market. [Banco Centrale de Nicaragua](https://www.bcn.gob.ni/estadisticas/mercados_cambiarios/index.php) sets a rate; banks, finance companies, exchange houses (casas de cambio), and independent agents can decide their own price, as you found at the border. A lot of small businesses also exchange currency, registered, and post their services and rates. Street corner money changers, coyotes, abound, of course.

Larger banks offering currency exchange:

- [Banpro](https://www.banprogrupopromerica.com.ni/)
- [Banco Ficohas](https://www.ficohsa.com/ni/nicaragua/banca-electronica-ficohsa/)

Casas de Cambio:

- [Global Exchange](http://www.global-exchange.com/en/branches/branches-in-country/branches-in-town/) Augusto C. Sandino International Airport, Carretera Norte Managua

  - International departures landside hall (daily 05:00 - 18:00)
  - International arrivals airside in front of the immigration desk (daily 07:00 - 23:00)
- [Casa De Empeño Prisa](http://www.prisa.com.ni/)

Some private banks and Credit Unions offer exchange services to customers (but no guarantee would do so for those who are not):

- [BDF - Banco de Finanzas](https://www.bdfnet.com/)
- [Caja Rural Nacional (CARUNA)](http://www.caruna.com.ni/)
- [Financiera FAMA](http://www.financierafama.com.ni/)

*Resources:*

[Nomas Operativas de las Casas de Cambio](http://legislacion.asamblea.gob.ni/normaweb.nsf/($All)/87228614C387990D062571930067D5F1?OpenDocument)

[Banking regulations in Nicaragua](https://centralamericadata.com/en/tsearch?q=Banking+regulations&q1=mattersInCountry_en_le%3A%22Nicaragua%22)

[La Prensa: La tasa de cambio de una empresa en el aeropuerto es inferior a la tasa oficial](https://www.laprensa.com.ni/2014/06/10/economia/197849-pagan-a-turistas-c20-66-por-1-dolar-la-tasa-de-cambio-de-una-empresa-en-el-aeropuerto-es-inferior-a-la-tasa-oficial)